# Why does insertBefore work weirdly with the span element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to add a span element before a referenced span element. However, there seems to be no space between the new element and the referenced span element.

[image]

```js
// Create a new, plain <span> element
let sp1 = document.createElement("span");

// Set class attribute and value
sp1.setAttribute("class", "new-element");

// Write content to element
sp1.innerText = "foo bar";
// Get the reference element
let sp2 = document.querySelector(".third-element");

// Get the parent element
let parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;

// Insert the new element into before sp2
parentDiv.insertBefore(sp1, sp2);
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
    <span>foo bar</span>
    <span>foo bar</span>
    <span class="third-element">foo bar</span>
    <span>foo bar</span>
</div>
```

Comment: so what's the outcome? And what's the error?

Comment: @TreeNguyen, Stack Overflow didnt let me append the screenshot of the outcome, so i have appended a onedrive link to that here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AghUk-zXVA_K63009r6Q7ujCFDIy?e=4GSLrU

Also, there is no error, just displays weirdly, other span elements have space between them, but not the appended and referenced elements.

Comment: do it `sp1.innerText = "foo bar\xa0";`. is an unbroken space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, you have a line break after each span element which ends up being turned into a space character (technically not a space character, but the browser shows it to you this way). When you add a span with javascript, it gets inserted inline like this:

`<span>new element</span><span>existing element</span>`

When spans are inline with no line break, the browser does not render that magic space character. The easiest fix for this is to add some `margin-right` with CSS, or to just to append a space character to the text in your spans like so:

`<span>This is my text </span>`

Comment: Is that line break a built-in style, cos honestly i didnt add that in the html. Could that be the case?

And thank you, your fix works fine. I was really confused, since i do not have any styling applied.

Comment: It's actually not a character, and I've updated the answer to reflect this. It gets rendered as "whitespace" by most browsers. You can actually see this in the Inspector in Firefox's devtools. Additionally, the browser will eliminate this whitespace if the preceding span ends with a space character, so you don't have to worry about having two spaces.